# How to connect to a remote Oracle server from Windows machine using PL/SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, windows

I understand that I need to configure database address in the [TNSNAMES.ORA](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora) file but where should I put this file?

**UPDATE**

I defined the `$TNS_ADMIN` variable, created the `TNSNAMES.ORA` file, added new connection and restarted my machine. Unfortunately, the *Database* list in *Oracle Logon* remains empty.

However, the following error occurred when I was trying out various options in PL/SQL Developer:

> Initialization error
>   SQL*Net not properly installed
>
> OracleHomeKey:
>   OracleHomeDir:

What is SQL*Net?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have SQL*Net installed in order to connect PL/SQL Dev to Oracle. SQL*Net is installed by default with most Oracle DB products (Oracle client for example). Since PL/SQL dev is a Windows app, you can see what Oracle products you have installed by looking into the registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle). Also in PL/SQL dev settings (Tools/Preferences/Connection) you will have a list of all Oracle Homes (which allows you to specify which one you want to use if you have multiple homes).

If you already have an Oracle Home, the `TNSNAMES.ora` file is by default in the directory `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin`. You can set the registry key `TNS_ADMIN` if you want to specify another directory.

Comment: I have no `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle` key. I tried to download Oracle client from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html and got the `instantclient-basic-nt-11.2.0.2.0.zip` file. How should I install it so it creates appropriate registry keys?

Comment: @Marek: I have little experience with the Instant Client. From the [FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/ic-faq-094177.html) it looks like some features require that you define an `ORACLE_HOME` system variable. The link also indicates how you could setup instantclient in the registry. I don't know if this would work with Pl/sql Developer (I've always used the Oracle full client).

Comment: @Marek: There is standalone client installation. Oracle Database 11g Release 2 Client (11.2.0.1.0) for Microsoft Windows (32-bit) - [otn.oracle.com](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win32soft-098987.html). During "Seclect Installation Type" choose "Administrator" and that's it. You can download/install/try anything from OTN, just make sure that you have correct license when go production.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an article way back when I was working with Oracle 10g about trying to connect to a database from a client with too many clients installed on it.

It does go through some basics though so you might want to have a look.

http://thetendjee.wordpress.com/2007/03/30/ora-12514-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-descriptor/

Otherwise yeah. Go for the full client rather than the instant client. I remember having a hard time getting it to work but since then it might have gotten better.

Comment: I forgot I did write about the instant client actually:
http://thetendjee.wordpress.com/2006/08/11/oracle-10g-instant-client-hard-to-make-it-work/

So, it should be very straight forward but you won't have the ODBC ability. You can only connect by normal oracle means.

Answer (score 0):

First close the window and then under Tool->Preferences->Oracle->Connection fill the following fields:

- Oracle Home (empty is autodetect): `C:\oracle`
- OCI library (empty is autodetect): `C:\oracle\bin\oci.dll`